# Avoid if block in my fetch Svelte component

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am fetching `JSON` from an external source in my Svelte project.

When I use `if` block around `await` block it works. But when I delete `if` block it gives an error of `object is undefined`.

How can I avoid using `if` block and be able to make it work? I don't get why `if` block makes the error go away.

It is a very simple script. You can see REPL by [clicking here](https://svelte.dev/repl/5ab77deee7d24f079a494aee38eec072?version=3.34.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing `program` to anything, so awaiting it throws an error. Setting it to the initial result of `fetchPrograms` will let you remove the if blocks. This is how the `{#await}` [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks) does it.

```html
<!-- Fetch.svelte -->
<script>
    export let url;
    let program = fetchPrograms();

    async function fetchPrograms(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        program = await response.json()
    }
    
    $: fetchPrograms(url)
</script>

<button on:click={() => url='https://reqres.in/api/users?page=4'} style="color:red">
    Fetch
</button>
{#await program}
xx
{:then item}
<p style="color:red">
    {item.page}
</p>
{:catch error}
omg
{/await}
```